# opencv count rectangle that frame divided into 4 section

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a haar cascade project that counts cars from video frame by frame, and I start wondering is it possible to divide 1 frame into 4 sections and count the car for each section. For example, I have this frame.

[image: frame]

as you can see this frame has 4 screens/sections and I want the haar cascade count the car for each section, but the algorithm that I created only count for 2 section (above and below screens)

```
    for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
        # divide screen for 4 screen and count the car
        if x < img.shape[1]/2:
            car_count1 += 1
        elif x < img.shape[1]/2*3:
            car_count2 += 1
        elif x < img.shape[1]/2*5:
            car_count3 += 1
        else:
            car_count4 += 1
```

[image: result]

For "screen 1" is the above screen that has 8 rectangles, and "screen 2" for below screen that has 13 rectangles. I know the problem is from the `elif x < img.shape[1]/2*5:` and `else:`, but I don't know the right `condition` for this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all you probably want to use the centerpoint of your rectangles to count it for the right frame

```
centerx = x+w/2
centery = y+h/2
```

Your image areas are x < 0.5width and also y < 0.5height for the top left, x > 0.5width and y < 0.5height for top right and so on.

```
if centerx < img.shape[1]/2 and centery < img.shape[0]/2:
    count1 += 1
if centerx >= img.shape[1]/2 and centery < img.shape[0]/2:
    count2 += 1
if centerx < img.shape[1]/2 and centery >= img.shape[0]/2:
    count3 += 1
if centerx >= img.shape[1]/2 and centery >= img.shape[0]/2:
    count4 += 1
```